# Curl, submitting form with __multiselect parameter

Tags: php, forms, servlets, curl

I'm trying to submit a (java servlet) form using CURL in PHP, but it seems like there is a problem with the parameters. I cant really understand why its happening since I'm testing the CURL with a identical string parameters that is being used by the browser.

After some research in diverse forums I wasn't able to find a solution to my particular problem.

this is the POSTFIELDS string generated by the browser (and working):

```
submissionType=pd&__multiselect_PostCodeList=&selectedPostCode=01&selectedPostCode=02&selectedPostCode=03&__multiselect_selectedPostCodes=
```

and I'm using and identical (for testing) string in the PHP script but it im getting a HTML file as a answers telling "Missing parameters in search query".

I believe that the form

```
__multiselect_PostCodeList=
&selectedPostCode=01
&selectedPostCode=02
&selectedPostCode=03
&__multiselect_selectedPostCodes=
```

is quite wired (never see before this) and I'm wondering that it can be the reason of why the post is not working from CURL.

The form seems to be successfully submitted since I'm getting this header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 07 Aug 2013 08:02:56 GMT
Content-length: 1791
Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Note: I tried submitting the same form from *Lynx* and I'm also getting the same result ("Missing parameters in search query"). So it seems like its only working with browsers like Mozilla or Chrome.

Please some help will be really appreciated, I don't have any more ideas at this point.

Thanks!
Oscar